# wordpress "Error establishing a database connection" Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I moved one wordpress website from localhost (xampp) to live server(subfolder ie www.mydomain.com/demo). Move all the files and upload the database file and change the wp-config.php file.

Then I visited my website from live server , landing page (home), backend admin (wp-admin) is working fine and I am able to use the backend admin and can edit and save, But when I am clicking on menu page loading and saying

**Error establishing a database connection**

I think database connection is working fine bcz home page is working and backend also.I tried to create a page and that time also its showing the same error.

**www.mydomain.com/demo**
 is working when I am looking any page like
**www.mydomain.com/demo/contact**
it's showing db connection error.

Comment: Could we have the url of your website maybe? It must be an error in routing anyway. In xamp did you set up a virtual host?

Comment: run this query `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost/test/', 'www.yourlivesite.com/');`